Using py7zr is there a way to set compression level?
Looking at the documentation there is not much info on this.
import py7zr
with py7zr.SevenZipFile("test.7z", 'w') as archive:
    archive.write("somefile.txt")

Theres a snippet at the bottom of https://py7zr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html
That talks about "filters"
[{'id': FILTER_DELTA}, {'id': FILTER_LZMA2, 'preset': PRESET_DEFAULT}]

where I figured 'preset' might be related, but looking at the source code it does not appear so.
Is it always at max compression level? or can I force it to the max?

Preset is related, and it comes from the standard LZMA module. "The preset argument (if provided) should be an integer between 0 and 9 (inclusive), optionally OR-ed with the constant PRESET_EXTREME."

@DanMašek can you reference the doc for that?

I looked at the implementation: https://github.com/miurahr/py7zr/blob/master/py7zr/properties.py#L127 The cited sentence is from documentation of lzma module
